# How to check if foreign key constraint fails when deleting record

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, sql-server-2005

I have created a database in SQL Server and front end is PHP - CodeIgniter. In the database I have created multiple foreign keys with other tables. Now when the user tries to delete the record, instead of really deleting I want to flag the record as `deleted = 1`, this should only be done when there will be no reference records are available in child table. Below are example tables:

```
Parent_Table
Id INT(PK), Name Varchar, deleted INT

Child_Table
Id INT(PK), FK_Parent_Table_ID INT, address varchar, deleted INT
```

Above is just example of my tables. Now whenever a user tries to delete a record from the parent table foreign key will check for constraint and then delete the record, here instead of actual deletion I want it flag as `deleted = 1`.

I have tried using `transaction->start` and `transaction->complete` so if foreign key fails the transaction gets aborted but here the problem is if the foreign key not failing then the rollback will occur and in that case the `PRIMARY KEY` of the record will be changed that should not be done.

So, I want a way to check the foreign key conflict before transaction starts without actual deletion of the record

Answer (score 1):

To implement what you are asking, just check for the existence of a record in the child table e.g.

```
declare @RecordToDelete int = 123;

-- Delete the record if no child records exist
delete
from Parent_Table
where id = @RecordToDelete
and not exists (select 1 from Child_Table where FK_Parent_Table_ID = @RecordToDelete);

-- Flag the record as deleted if child records exist
update Parent_Table set
    Deleted = 1
where id = @RecordToDelete
and exists (select 1 from Child_Table where FK_Parent_Table_ID = @RecordToDelete);
```

Depending on whether you really need to keep the record, because you could always create your foreign keys with a cascade delete.

With 15+ child tables I would seriously consider just always flagging the record as deleted and never bothering to actually delete those without child records. A few extra records is unlikely to make much difference to your database.

---

Actually in my experience child tables fall into 2 categories:

- Those that can automatically be deleted using a cascade delete
- Those that should prevent us from deleting the parent record

If this is the case the checks required should become more manageable.

---

Also for these situations I recommend encapsulating the delete logic within a stored procedure in order to keep it all in one place, and be easy to modify if the database schemes changes in future.

---

Note: Personally I would make the `Deleted` column a `bit` rather than an `int` as it more accurately reflects the intention.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but in my case there are more then 15+ tables which are referenced so it will not quite possible to check each and every table via query.

Comment: @Niks Its totally possible, and its the only way.

Comment: @Niks also you need to ensure your question is complete with all relevant information i.e. the number of child tables.

Comment: @Niks . . . This appears to answer the question that you actually asked.  And if it does then you should accept it.  If you didn't ask the question you intended, ask a *new* question.  Don't play a game of "guess my real problem".